# Jordan form generating general vectors vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

given a Matrix or function, we been told to find jordan form of it. once we have found char poly, e-vals. We need to find e-vectors. Suppose we found them by rref or how gilbert strang shows us. my question is will we there be always be a solution that is $(A-I\lambda)^p x=0$ that is $(A-I\lambda)^{p-1} x $ is a vanilla  e-vector. 
 for example will there always be a solution by doing the inverse of each recursively like if p=3  the dot diagram would be like 
 $$\begin{aligned} *(A-I\lambda)^2 v_1
\\ *(A-I\lambda)(v_1) 
\\ *(v_1)  
\end{aligned}$$
will this method ***always*** yeild a $v_1$

---

I recall one time I could not find the $v_1$ by recursively finding the inverses there was an instance where there was no solution. I had to change the eigenvectors to some wierd combination that was not the original how strang finds the e-vectors but I cannot recreate it.

***My linear algebra teacher*** says that there always be a $v_1$ doing it the way of finding the inverse which I do not think so. I think there is times where there is no solution. And says that there it is always jordan form ( do think so.)

here is the sample I was talking about.

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 2& -1& 0& 1 \\ 0 & 3& -1& 0 \\ 0& 1& 1& 0 \\ 0& -1& 0 &3 \end{pmatrix}$$

this is ex 2 on 7.2 of linear algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence but I am finding e-vectors like I learned in linear one. the char poly is $(t-2)^3 (t-3)$. so

- $\lambda_1 =2$ with a.m 3
- $\lambda_2 =3 $ with mult 1

We will find  eigenvector of $ \lambda_1$

$$ \begin{aligned} A-\lambda_1 I &= 
                  \begin{pmatrix} 
                         2-2& -1& 0& 1 
                      \\ 0 & 3-2& -1& 0
                      \\ 0& 1& 1-2& 0 
                      \\ 0& -1& 0 &3-2
                  \end{pmatrix}
\\ &= \begin{pmatrix} 
                         0& -1& 0& 1 
                      \\ 0 & 1 & -1& 0
                      \\ 0& 1& -1& 0 
                      \\ 0& -1& 0 &1
                  \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$
get that 
  $$rref(A-\lambda_1 I)= \begin{pmatrix} 
                         0& 1& 0& -1 
                      \\ 0 & 0 & 1& -1
                      \\ 0& 0& 0& 0 
                      \\ 0& 0& 0 &0
                  \end{pmatrix} $$
$x_1 =1,x_4=0 \Rightarrow (1,0,0,0)$ and $x_4=1,x_1=0 \Rightarrow (0,1,1,1)$. Those are our 2 e-vectors

Doing the dot diagram we get that
$$\begin{matrix} * (T-I\lambda_1)v_1 & *v_2
                   \\     *v_1   &  \end{matrix} $$
now  assume $(T-\lambda I)v_1=(1,0,0,0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1,1,1)$

we need to find $v_1$ that is 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1& 0& 1
               \\ 0 & 1  &-1& 0 
                 \\ 0& 1 &-1 &0
\\                 0&-1&0&1  \end{pmatrix} v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so  $$  rref \begin{pmatrix} 0 &-1& 0& 1& |&1 
                     \\ 0 &1& -1& 0& |& 0 
                     \\ 0 &1& -1& 0& |& 0 
                      \\0 &-1& 0& 1& |& 0\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0& -1&  & | &-1 
               \\ 0 &0& 1& -1& & |&-1 
                \\ 0& 0& 0& 0& & |&0 
                \\0& 0& 0& 0&  & | &-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
**No solution.** maybe $v_1 = (0,1,1,1)$ so,

$$rref \begin{pmatrix} 0 &-1& 0& 1& |& 0 
                     \\ 0 &1& -1& 0& |& 1 
                     \\ 0 &1& -1& 0& |& 1 
                      \\0 &-1& 0& 1& |& 1 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0& -1& |& 0 
                     \\ 0 &0& 1& -1& |& 0 
                     \\ 0 &0& 0& 0& |& 1 
                      \\0 &0& 0& 0& |& 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
also no solution. So this ***method does not work all the time to find basis jordan form*** . I am being told that this method will always work.

***Did I do something wrong with counter example??*** *I do want to email him this*. I am not saying there is no jordan form just that this way does not work all the time just sometimes as long as started with e-vectors that work

Comment: Perhaps you were dealing with a case where there were two different Jordan blocks with the same eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AP = PJ

$(A - 2I)^2v = 0$

$\begin{pmatrix}0&-2&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&-2&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}$

Av = $\begin{pmatrix}3&2&2&1\\
0&3&-1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

$AP = PJ$

$\begin{pmatrix}3&2&2&1\\
0&3&-1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I know what the solution is. I know there is a alternate way to find it. I know  it because it is on the book I just do not want to rewrite it. $K_{\lambda_1}= \{(-1,-1,-1,-1),(0,1,2,0),(1,0,0,0) \} $ and where first and last are e-vectors

Comment: sorry, this is they way that I know how to do it, and I wasn't following your work.